# Update Panels Not Updating

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

This is one of those questions I fear nobody will be able to answer, but there's no harm in asking!

I have lots of `UpdatePanels` on my ASP.NET page.  When a user enters a value in a particular field, other controls are enabled or disabled accordingly.  So far, each panel I've added has worked just fine, until now.

I have a `RadioButtonList` with three options - Yes, No and Unknown.  If the user selects Yes, a textbox in an `UpdatePanel` should become enabled.  What actually happens is that it updates... sometimes.  The pattern seems to be that whichever option in the `RadioButtonList` is selected when the page loads is the one that DOESN'T trigger the `UpdatePanel` if you change the option to something else and then back again.  For example, if the page loads and Unknown is selected, changing the selection to Yes or No correctly enable and disable the textbox as often as you care to click them, but changing the selection to Unknown does not disable the textbox as it should.  Like I said, that pattern holds true whichever is the selected value when the page loads.

Stranger still, if I select the value which does not trigger the update as it should, and then change the value in a totally unrelated control which is the trigger for a different `UpdatePanel`, when that second panel updates, so does the first one which had failed to update up until that time.  That's despite the fact that ALL of my `updatepanels` are set to Conditional update mode.

I've shown my code below.  Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction!

```
<tr class="grouprow">
    <td>Non-Abdominal Surgery In Last 6 Months?</td>
    <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblRecentNonAbdominalSurgery" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AdmissionRecentNonAbdominalSurgery")%>' 
        CssClass="bottommargin" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblRecentNonAbdominalSurgery_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="AutoID" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Unknown" Value="" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" />                                    
    </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
</tr>
<tr class="grouprow">
    <td>Non-Abdominal Surgery Description</td>
    <td><asp:UpdatePanel ID="updRecentNonAbdominalSurgery" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rblRecentNonAbdominalSurgery" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />    
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRecentNonAbdominalSurgeryDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AdmissionRecentNonAbdominalSurgeryDescription")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Rows="4" CssClass="multilinetextbox bottommargin" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel></td>
</tr>
```

And the code behind:

```
Dim rblPreviousColicSurgery As RadioButtonList = fvPreviousColic.FindControl("rblPreviousColicSurgery")
If rblPreviousColicSurgery.SelectedItem.Text = "Yes" Then
    txtPreviousColicSurgeryDescription.Enabled = True
Else
    txtPreviousColicSurgeryDescription.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple update panels and not just one which wraps all the controls?

Comment: Several reasons: My controls are in a table (an ACTUAL table, not a lazy way of laying out the page), and UpdatePanels which span TDs cause problems (I tried). Also, to try and minimise the amount of data sent during the async postback, though I understand that updatepanel model doesn't actually reduce this as much as we might like.

Comment: I think the answer lies in the second comment here: http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2009/04/radiobuttonlist-error-with-updatepanels.html. Just need to implement it for my own purposes now, after which I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've come up with this fix, and was quite pleased with myself that it worked first time!  The problem is caused because when a `RadioButtonList` is designated as an asynchronous trigger for an `UpdatePanel`, JavaScript code to perform the asynchronous postback is added to each item in the `RadioButtonList` when the page is rendered, APART FROM THE ITEM SELECTED.  So, we need to add the code to that item manually.

I've created a class and added this sub to it:

```
Public Shared Sub AddJavaScriptToItem(ByVal rbl As RadioButtonList, ByVal selectedindex As Integer)

    Dim clientid As String = rbl.ClientID
    rbl.SelectedItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'" & clientid & "$" & selectedindex & "\',\'\')',0)")

End Sub
```

I can then easily call this sub from anywhere on my site where a `RadioButtonList` which is an AysncPostbackTrigger is loaded (e.g. in the DataBound event of a FormView).